# Releasing disk space on guest, reduces free space on host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware-player

I am using vmplayer on Windows 7 with guest os = Ubuntu 12.04

I have faced this situation before, so this time I carefully noticed. Below is what happened:

1. I empty the trash in Ubuntu. The free space on ubuntu jumps from 11.7 GB to 13.4 GB.
2. I immediately switch to windows, the free space lowers from 49.3 GB to 49.2 GB

Why is this happening?

**EDIT-** when I release space on guest, my intent is to release space on host. So is this not possible? If yes how can I actually free up space on both host and guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related on how file systems work.
When deleting files, traditional file systems in fact mark the file record in their file allocation table as deleted. They don't "free up" any space. That space is simply not referenced by anyone.

You have an *autoexpanding* virtual drive. When deleting, your file system is only accessing his internal file allocation table and *marking* old space as deleted. This involves some new writes to the file system (for journaling for example) and thus the virtual drive asks new space to the *host* to provide it to the *guest*.

Instead a fixed size virtual drive will act as a physical hard drive and you won't see what the file system is doing in his partitions.

Useful links:

- [Basic article on how file systems work](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1220426)
- [Ext, Ext2, Ext3](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Filesystems-HOWTO-6.html) (advanced)

Comment: Fixed-size virtual drive won't be much help, though. In won't grow, but it will be as big as autoexpanded drive can be when full. If the problem is that disk image grows, then making it big from the very beginning isn't a solution.

Comment: @gronostaj OP asked 'why'. :) My answer was only to explain why it happens and why it won't happen otherwise in a fixed-sized virtual drive. :) This is also why snapshot size normally grows over time.

Comment: +1 Thanks for explanation. As an additional question -- when I release space on guest, my intent is to release space on host. So is this not possible? If yes how can I actually free up space on both host and guest?

Comment: @Vinayak : You can use vmware guest tools to shrink the size of the image. The tool copies every used sector into a new vmware disk image and then deletes the old image. Note that you require nearly double the disk space of the vmware disk image during this process.